# Is facebook profile "view as" feature exists also in the graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has this option in their gui of viewing your own profile as is seen by someone else.
My question is, is there any similar thing in the graph API?

i.e. - Can I, given an user's access token, tell what other groups of people (say his friends) can see about him? (or if a specific detail in his profile is viewable by this group).
I searched in the documentation but didnt find anything, and also, the privacy field is limited to posts, photos and videos, and does not contain other information - So I'm looking for ways to work this around and to be able to tell what detail is accessable to which person.
Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Facebook support. Visit (Help center)[https://stackoverflow.com/help] to find what questions are on-topic here. And many other fascinating things.

Comment: well, stackoverflow is indeed facebook support... visit
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545 to find out

Comment: No it does not exists in the API

Comment: is there any way to get this kind of information?

Comment: No. Why would you need this?